Augmented triple complex
Premise
An augmented double complex is basically a double complex in which we put some "emphasis" on the first column

Clearly an augmented double complex induces a cochain morphism $\Phi:D^\bullet \to \text{Tot}(C^{\bullet\bullet})$ where $\text{Tot}(C^{\bullet\bullet})$ is the total complex of the double complex $C^{\bullet \bullet}$.
It's a well known fact (see Bott,Tu page 96-97) if the rows of an augmented double complex are exact, then $\Phi$ is a quasi-isomorphism, so $H^k(D^\bullet)\cong H^k(C^{\bullet\bullet})$ for any $k\geq0$.
My question
We can define an augmented triple complex $(D^{\bullet\bullet},C^{\bullet\bullet\bullet})$ in the same fashion. I'm not skilled enough to produce the diagram in Latex though! Basically we have a double complex morphism $$D^{\bullet\bullet}\to C^{\bullet 0 \bullet}$$ that connects $D^{\bullet\bullet}$ to the triple complex $C^{\bullet\bullet\bullet}$.
Clearly this induces a morphism $\Phi:\text{Tot}(D^{\bullet \bullet})\to \text{Tot}(C^{\bullet \bullet \bullet})$.
If the augmented (single) complexes $(D^{mn},C^{m\bullet n})$ are exact is it true that $\Phi$  is a quasi-isomorphism?
In other words, does the result from Bott,Tu generalize to triple complexes.
